Definition of boundary points in topological space
Please can anyone help me to understand definition of boundary points in topological space. My professor gave me the following definition of boundary points.
Let $(X, U)$ be a topological space, $x \in X$ and $S \subseteq X$.
Then $x$ is called a boundary point of $S$ if any neighborhood of $x$ intersects both $S$ and $S^C$.
We call this set the boundary of S and denote it $∂S$.
Logically I understand that the boundary points have to be located on the boundary of set S.
But if we take, for example, $U = \{\emptyset, X\}$. By this definition we have that the only neighborhood of each point belonging to $X$ is $X$. So in this topology all points are boundary points. Do I misunderstand something? Please help me.

"So in this topology all points are boundary points" of which $S$? This is true except for $S=\varnothing$ or $X$.

Correct. The topology you described on $X$, the indiscrete topology, is a special case. Inside this topology, every point is, to use a non-technical phrase, indistinguishable from each other because they are all close together. Topologically speaking, your space $X$ is essentially equivalent to studying the only topology on a singleton.
E: With the important amendment by Anne Bauval that this isn't true for the empty set or the entire space.
